# How to mock axios in outer function?

Tags: typescript, axios, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

How to mock `HTTP` responses from `axios` in outer function?
I have wrapper function for `GET` request in `axios`:

```
export const getRequest = async (
    url: string,
    queryParams: { [key: string]: string; } = {},
    headers: { [key: string]: string; } = {}
): Promise<IhttpResponse> => {
    const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
        url: url,
        method: 'get',
        headers: headers,
        params: new URLSearchParams(queryParams)
    };
    const response = await axios(config);
    return {status: response.status, body: response.data};
}
```

This wrapper function called in other function:

```
export const getCards = async () => {
    const url = `${backendUrl}/card`;
    const res = await getRequest(url);
    return res;
}
```

And I have `Jest` test:

```
import {getCards} from "@/cards_api";
import axios from "axios";
jest.mock("@/http-methods.ts");

test("test one", async () => {
    (axios.get as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve({status: 200, data: {'key': 'value'} })
    );
    const r = await getCards();
    console.log(r);
});
```

But it falls with error `TypeError: _axios.default.get.mockImplementation is not a function`

**How to correctly test `getCards` with mocked data?**

Comment: there's a `jest-mock-axios` npm module designed to achieve the behaviour https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to mock the `axios` module itself rather then your api module.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getCards } from '@/cards_api';

jest.mock('axios');

test("test one", async () => {
    axios.mockResolvedValue({ status: 200, data: { 'key': 'value' } });
    const { status } = await getCards();
    expect(status).toBe(200);
});
```

using the `jest-mock-axios' [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios) might also be an option for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working: falls with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')` because `response` in `getRequest` is `undefined`. This mock is not working. I'll try module that you suggest

Comment: oh, i've missed your method uses the `axios()` call itself. you should mock it, rather then the `axios.get()`

Comment: the solution is updated now

Comment: thx. One more question: to mock `axios` returned value in other `axios` call, we need to mock exactly `axois` itself?

Comment: depends on the call itself. `axios()` is mocked here because it's called itself. e.g. if you will use`axios.get()` , the mock implementation should be assigned to the method.